# Caret in Qt application has little triangle on the right

Tags: gui, qt, caret

When I type into text field in Qt application ([SQLite Studio](https://sqlitestudio.pl)), I see a little triangle on the right side of blinking caret:

Lorem ipsum[image: the caret]

I pasted to the field using middle click before. This caret is visible only on two lines, other show classic “line.”

What does this caret shape mean?

Comment: What did you paste? The caret indicates bidirectional input for mixing left-to-right and right-to-left languages.

Comment: @JamesP I pasted text from HTML e-mail message (from SeaMonkey). It should be only Latin Extended and some special characters like `-:,` etc.